# GSAP on scroll motion

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I want to achieve this [attached photo's title part] scroll motion [link here](https://datavisual.nl/) result.

I've tried to implement the same scroll motion with GSAP. [codepen link here](https://codepen.io/Zihad24/pen/JjrxgGB). Please suggest if you know a better way to implement the scroll up/down motion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE0Iw.png)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io) seems to do just that... it's the go-to solution.

Comment: GSAP has [scrolltrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GSAP on scroll motion with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814884/gsap-on-scroll-motion-with-loop)